# Unity3D does not generate local notifications when not running in the background

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ibeacon

I have made my own plugin that listens for iBeacons in iOS. The plugin basically registers for local notifications and when it's within the range of my beacon it generates a notification.

The problem is when I integrate that with Unity3D **(placing my .h and .mm files in /Plugins/iOS)** when the unity player is not running in the background (not open), my unity won't generate local notification, but if it is in the background it works just fine.

Could it be that unity is overriding my notification settings that have in my .mm file? and if it is so, how can I fix this issue.

Thank you in advance.